# CakePHP Form without formhelper

Tags: php, cakephp, formhelper

I have a little doubt here about not using FormHelper:
I have a register form, something like that:

```
<form method="POST" action="/myController/saveData">
    <input type="text" name="data[Model][Field]"/>
</form>
```

am I right?

Comment: yes, that looks correct.

Comment: Yes, but if you are using AuthComponent and you plan to use AJAX in the future then I have bad news for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but - there's an easy way to verify for sure.

When in doubt, just use the FormHelper temporarily.  For example, lets say you have complex associations or lots of fields, and you're not SURE the input names that you need (and for some reason you don't want to use the FormHelper) just write it using the FormHelper, look at the source it generates, then use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely right, you can create forms like this!